# ALT+TAB doesn't work properly in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, alt-tab

Holding ALT+TAB will activate the flip 2D to switch from a window to another. The problem is that this function remains active for a very short time and I'm not able to select the window I want in the foreground. I also noticed that when I put the cursor on an icon on the taskbar, the live preview thumbnail disappears quickly.

I noticed that this problem disappears in 2 situations:
1) with a safe mode restart
2) when I deactivate the charging of the battery from the manufacturer(Dell) software for the battery.

PS I can't remove manually the battery because the laptop is unibody.

Any suggestions for this annoiyng problem?

Comment: Do you have any keyboard modification programs?  Like autohotkey?

Comment: No. I only have manufacturer system driver and some software like Office, Chrome, Firefox, Spotify ecc...

Comment: I've seen the same problem on Lenovo laptops, it came and went. I can only assume it is some kind of driver issue because it stopped after some update but I'm not sure which.

Comment: I don't know Julian. This morning I completely formatted my laptop and with no software and drivers the problem resurfaced again. Maybe it's something related to BIOS?

Comment: I have a Lenovo T440s with Win8.1U1x64.  I found that the problem only happens when it is on power supply. Pull out the cable and Alt-TAB no longer disappears after some seconds. What's more: it seems to be gone for a while after you plug in the power again... strange.